# is it calling a Overriden method in a overriding method using "super", are we doing overloading with the call?

Tags: java, methods, overloading, overriding

Does it represent both overriding and overloading at same time? in class B

```
public class A{
    void someMethod(){
    System.out.println("Class A's some method");
    }
}

class B extends A{
    void someMethod(){
    super.someMethod();   // does this line reperesnt overloading of super class method??
    System.out.println("Class B's some method");
    }
}
```

Comment: You just need to Google what "Overload" means to answer that yourself ... What is you "reason" for not doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no method overloading in this code snippet. Overloading occurs when two methods with a different list of arguments (either different number of arguments or different types of arguments) have the same name.

And the overriding occurs simply due to class `B` having a method with the same signature and access level as class `A` - `someMethod()`. It doesn't make a difference whether `B`'s implementation of that method executes `A`'s implementation (using `super.someMethod()`) or not.

Comment: can we say, the behavior is overloaded?

Comment: @vinaybayyaram I don't know what you mean by that, but the term overloading has a different meaning in Java.